# Excel Formula - How To Collapse Empty Data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using the formula below to create / compile data from other cells to form a description:

```
=H2 & "<br><br>" & I2 & "<br>" & "Other Details: " & "<br>" & SC!Q2  & "<br>" & SC!R2 & "<br>" & SC!S2 & "<br><br>" & SC!U2
```

The issue I have is that after "Other Details" SC!Q2, SC!R2 and SC!S2 do not always have data in them, so the information displayed has several empty lines / blank spaces. I would like to collapse / suppress that information if the field is empty.

Is this something i can do within the formula?

Comment: Please state your problem or question with background information. It might be difficult for anyone to figure out your problem and suggest a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that's easy to understand but it's going to make your formula longer. There's a function called `ISBLANK` that you can use for each piece.

```
=H2 & "<br><br>" & I2 & "<br>" & "Other Details: " & IF(ISBLANK(SC!Q2),"","<br>" & SC!Q2)  & IF(ISBLANK(SC!R2),"","<br>" & SC!R2) & IF(ISBLANK(SC!S2),"","<br>" & SC!S2) & "<br><br>" & SC!U2
```

You could also wrap the entire thing in a few `SUBSTITUTE` functions. I say use more than one because `=SUBSTITUTE("aaaa","aa","a")` returns `aa` instead of `a` and there are some instances when you want two line breaks in a row.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(H2 & "<br><br>" & I2 & "<br>" & "Other Details: " & "<br>" & SC!Q2  & "<br>" & SC!R2 & "<br>" & SC!S2 & "<br><br>" & SC!U2, "<br><br><br>", "<br><br>"), "<br><br><br>", "<br><br>"), "<br><br><br>", "<br><br>")
```